# Windows App Certification Kit - error

Tags: c#, windows, wack

I am developing a Windows 8 application. I tested the app with Windows Certification Kit, and it was throwing the following error:

Debug configuration test

> FAILED
>
> Debug configuration
>
> • Error Found: The debug configuration test detected the following errors:◦The binary myappname.exe is built in debug mode.
>
> • Impact if not fixed:  Windows Store doesn’t allow a debug version of an app.
>
> • How to fix:  Please make sure the app isn’t linking to any debug versions of a framework, and it is built with release configuration. If this is a managed app please make sure you have installed the correct version of .NET framework.

Any suggestions on what this means and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Build the app in release configuration before testing...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to rebuild your application in release mode then re-run the certification test, the test will never pass if you build Debug.